# Alternative to setInterval to update values of API call

Tags: javascript, html, api

I'm currently using setInterval to call an API request every 10 seconds,

But instead of updating the value it adds values to the page

I think it is because I've designed the code to be += when calling values.

I do not know what to use instead...

The plunk to see it at work
https://plnkr.co/edit/BEdYpVhJGCXyTPnAP482?p=preview

```
 // Code goes here
var time = setInterval(function(){

const url = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=xbtusd"; // Change 
this 
to your URL
fetch(url,{ mode: "cors"})
.then(function(response) {
      if(response.status == 200) { // Check if response went through
          response.json().then(function(data) { 
              console.log(data); 
              var price_USD = document.getElementById('price-usd');
              var USDPrice = '<p>BTCUSD Price:' + 
((data.result.XXBTZUSD.c[0])*1.1).toFixed(2) + '$' + '</p>';
              price_USD.innerHTML += USDPrice;
          });
      } else { // Response wasn't ok. Check dev tools
          console.log("response failed?");
          console.log(response); 
      } 
});


const urleur = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=xbteur"; // Change 
this to your URL
fetch(urleur,{ mode: "cors"})
.then(function(response) {
      if(response.status == 200) { // Check if response went through
          response.json().then(function(data) { 
              console.log(data); 
              var price_USD = document.getElementById('price-usd');
              var USDPrice = '<p>BTCEUR Price:' + 
((data.result.XXBTZEUR.c[0])*1.1).toFixed(2) + '€' +  '</p>';
              price_USD.innerHTML += USDPrice;
          });
      } else { // Response wasn't ok. Check dev tools
          console.log("response failed?");
          console.log(response); 
      } 
});

},10000);
```

Comment: Do you need to update the text `BTCUSD Price` every time?  Put a span around only the price itself, and update it with `.innerHTML = yourNewPrice`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 bugs.

1. Both functions are updating the price_USD element.
2. instead of `price_USD.innerHTML += USDPrice;` you can do `price_USD.innerHTML = USDPrice;` and `price_EUR.innerHTML = EURPrice;`

Comment: Indeed, it is this that makes an issue

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I changes the += into just =

And I divided the blocks, instead of having 1 block div for both price, each price has now its own div